# Positive definite matrix proof with post

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ a positive-definite matrix and a matrix $B\in M_{nxp}(\mathbb{R})$, with $n\geq p$ and $rank(B)=p$. Show that
$$C=B^tAB$$ is positive definite.
I have no idea of how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ x\neq 0 \Rightarrow Bx\neq 0 $$

So $$ \langle B^tABx,x\rangle = \langle A(Bx),Bx \rangle > 0$$

Comment: A small doubt you did not use the rank?

Comment: Yes if b has not rank p then bx may be 0